# jquery load data without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, calendar

I have a php calendar where i use next and prev link to go through next month or previous month. I want it to load calendar data without page refresh and i'm unable to figure it.

my next link produce like :

```
http://localhost/blog3/blog?month=03&year=2017 and
```

prev link like:

```
http://localhost/blog3/blog?month=01&year=2017
```

and here my calendar is not included from other page. also my if i click next or prev its load entire page in calendar div.

[jquery]

```
    $('#cprev').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var pmonth = Pmonth;
    var pyear = Pyear;
    var url = 'http://localhost/blog3/blog?month='+pmonth+'&year='+pyear;

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: url,
        data: {pmonth:"pmonth",pyear:"pyear"},

        success: function(result){
            $('.calendar').html(result);
        },
        error: function(){
        }
   });
    return false;
});
```

in my main page

```
<script>
 var Pmonth = <?php echo($prev_month); ?>;
 var Pyear = <?php echo($prev_year); ?>;
 var Nmonth = <?php echo($next_month); ?>; 
 var Nyear = <?php echo($next_year); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Is **#cprev** an anchor or a button? Where do you get the variables **Pmonth** and **Pyear** from?

Comment: first thing is comma missing after url:url, and make sure what reusult you sending from server side..

Comment: It seems like if you are returning a full http response. You need to return the partial html which you want to render into `.calendar`.

Comment: I update my post answering with your ques.how to solve please give a working example.

Comment: @babymachinery is **#cprev** an anchor or a button??

Comment: its an anchor not button

Comment: You need to use **event.preventDefault()** to prevent the anchor's default behavior (loading another page). Just add `e.preventDefault()` at the beginning of your function.

Comment: same thing i add e.preventDefault(); but not working. its still reloading my entire page

Comment: Phalcon has a thing about caching views. Have you made sure that `event.preventDefault()` is in your version? Ie: have you cleared the cache?

Comment: yeap! i cleared my cache. but same thing

Comment: Is there have any solutions for this problem cause I'm in same situation.